# How to get the sum of categories with respect to other variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, categorical-data

I have a DataFrame , with multiple columns , but i'll display the ones that i need :

```
 DF.head():

 Modality          Year          Month
 Cash               2019           1
 Credit Card        2019           3
 Bank Transfer      2018           5
```

What I want to do is to get the sum of each modality for each month for each year , like this :

```
  Year       Month      Modality 
                        Cash              1500
               1        Credit Card       1400
                        Bank Transfer     1245

                        Cash              1423
  2018         2        Credit Card       1222
                        Bank Transfer     2125
```

This is How i tried to do it :

```
   Number_Of_Modality = DF.groupby(['Year','Month','Modality'])['Modality'].count()
```

And This is What I got:

```
     Year  Month  Channel
     2018  1      Card              16694
                  Credit Card        663
                  Bank Transfer      29
           2      Card      15818
                  Credit Crad          2
           3      Bank Transfer      11839
                  Card                587
                  Credit Card          22
           .
           .
           .
     2019         Card                663
                  Credit Card         29
           2      Bank Transfer      15818
           .
           .
```

Any Suggestion if what i did is right ? , Thank you.

Comment: I think you query running while for what you need

Comment: I'm sorry i did not understand !!

Comment: Your example doesn't include the amounts you are summing. Also the end of your groupby should be .sum()

Comment: I just want to get the sum of every modalities for each month of the year 2018 and the year 2019.

Comment: Your example doesn't show the amounts. It only shows category, year, and month.

Comment: What did you get from your code and why weren't you satisfied with the output?

Comment: I'll add it right away.

Answer (score 1):

In the DataFrame you presented, *Modality*, *Year* and *Month* are columns
to group by.
If you want to **sum** something, there must be some other column - values
to be summed for each group.
I assumed this column is called *Val*.

So to sum *Val* values for each group you defined, run:

```
df.groupby(['Year','Month','Modality']).Val.sum()
```

If the column to sum had different name, change it as needed.

Or maybe you want to **count** modality rows in each year / month?

In this case you should:

- group rows as before,
- for each group run *count()*, to count rows in the current group.

So the code should be:

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Modality']).count()
```

Comment: I've tried it beforehand and at the end it gave me the same resluts than the line of code that i ran , so i guess i'm on the right path.